# Apache mod_rewrite stop after first condition

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I'm trying to have this URL rewritten as follow:

- `fr.example.com/tag/movies` » `example.com/catch.php?country=fr&tag=movies`
- `example.com/tag/movies` » `example.com/catch.php?tag=movies`
- `fr.example.com` » `domain.com/catch.php?country=fr`

for these, I have the following mod_rewrite rules in a .htaccess file

- subdomain + tag

  ```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+) catch.php?country=%1&tag=$1 [L,NS]
  ```
- tag

  ```
  RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+) catch.php?tag=$1 [L,NS]
  ```
- subdomain

  ```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ catch.php?country=%1 [L,NS]
  ```

in this order exactly.

Now, the `L` after the first `RewriteRule` should end processing and redirect it to the subdomain+tag URL, but it doesn't. For example, `fr.example.com/tag/movies` is sent to `catch.php?country=fr`, which is the last condition in the `.htaccess` file.

Shouldn't it stop after the first `L` is found?

**ANSWER**

Well, it turns out that the `[L]` flag works differently depending on the context (`.htaccess`/`<Directory>` different from `httpd.conf`) as you can see [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l).

So, to make it work just place the rules inside the `<VirtualHost>` (NOT `<Directory>`) and add a `/` to every URI (`/catch.php`, `/tag`, ...). That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The L flag won't stop processing under all circumstances. I'd suggest checking out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775877/apache-mod-rewrite-rewriterule-with-l-argument-whats-wrong) thread on Stack Overflow, especially the link to the Apache Rewrite Guide, and also turning on the RewriteLog so that you can confirm how mod_rewrite is processing your rules.